# AMPscript Date formatting using format or formatdate not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have an `ORDER_DATE` attribute in my data extension which is of the text datatype. The date is in the following format `mm-dd-yyyy`.

Now I want to convert this date into European format based on locale but I am getting some error while converting it.

I am using the following piece of code:

```
%%[

  var @orderDate 
  set @orderDate = ORDER_DATE
  set @convertdate = FormatDate(@orderDate,"l","","en-GB") 
  Output(Concat("OrderDate: ", @convertdate))

]%%
```

Why the date is not showing me when I do preview and test??

Comment: I would verify your date values. I tested your code and it works correctly. Perhaps there are some that are either empty or malformed that are causing errors? As @JohannesSchapdick stated, it could be the special char. in your field name (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/languageElements.htm) that is causing the mismatch as well. I don't think I have had issues with underscores before, but it is possible. Try outputting just your `@orderDate` and verify the results.

Comment: Please update your question with a sample of text dates from your sending Data Extension.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your text dates are formatted, you many need to do some string manipulation before applying the formatting:

```
%%[

  var @orderDate 
  var @convertDate

  set @orderDate = AttributeValue("ORDER_DATE")
  output(concat("<br>orderDate: ", @orderDate))  

  set @convertdate = FormatDate(replace(@orderDate," ",""),"l","","en-GB") 
  output(concat("<br>convertdate: ", @convertdate))

]%%
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the thing is FormatDate() function takes input as datestring in the format YYYY-MM-DD.And the date format in my DataExtension was DD-MM-YYYY.
So I have used following code for converting it in to YYYY-MM-DD and then based on locale it is now converting in to European Format.

Following is the code-

```
     %%[ var @orderDate 
        set @orderDate = AttributeValue("ORDER_DATE")
        if indexOf(@orderDate, "-") > 0 then
         set @dd = Substring(@orderDate,1, Subtract(IndexOf(@orderDate,"-"),1))
       endif 
        if indexOf(@orderDate, "-") > 0 then
         set @MM = Substring(@orderDate,4, Subtract(IndexOf(@orderDate,"-"),1))
       endif
       Set @YYYY = Substring(@orderDate, SUBTRACT(Length(@orderDate), 3), 4) 
        set @dateformat=Concat(@YYYY,"-",@MM,"-", @dd)
         set @convertdate = FormatDate(@dateformat,"l","","en-GB") 
        output(concat("<br>convertdate: ", @convertdate))]%%
```

Please suggest if there is any better solution than this.!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
set @orderDate = ORDER_DATE
```

This code will not actually set a value into the variable orderDate. Is it a dataextension field? Probably yes -> thats why you would need to set the variable like this

```
set @orderDate = [ORDER_DATE]
```

Here is additional information about the formatdate function:

**- [Refence Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/FormatDate.htm)**

**- [Reference AMPScript Guide](https://ampscript.guide/formatdate/)**

Comment: I don't believe there is any functional difference between your two lines of AMPscript.  As far as I know, brackets aren't required unless there's a space in the variable name.

Comment: It is also needed for some special characters (e.g. `-`) but I honestly don't think that underscore is one that would require it. (ref: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/languageElements.htm)

Comment: Oh, yeah, dash.  Forgot about that one.

Answer (score 0):

Going off your answer that your dates are in the DD-MM-YYYY format, I would propose using a SQL query beforehand to correct this.

I recommend SQL as Format and FormatDate do not recognize or correctly handle 'day before month' date formats. They can output them, but they are not a recognized input.

Now the down and dirty SQL I would recommend using is: `CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(DATETIME, ORDER_DATE,103),101) as ORDER_DATE`

Basically what this does is take your varchar text date (Current ORDER_DATE) and convert it to a date data type (103 - which is DD-MM-YYYY). From there it then does another convert to turn the 'Day First Date' to a 'Month First Date' which is easier for most date related functions to accept as an input.

I would recommend adding a second date field here in the DE if possible. Something like `ORDER_DATE_FORMAT` and have it be nullable and be an actual date type. This will then also keep your original ORDER_DATE info in the DE untocuhed.

So for instance, after you run the SQL, in your email you would have:

```
%%[
  set @orderDate = AttributeValue("ORDER_DATE_FORMAT") 

  set @convertdate = FormatDate(replace(@orderDate," ",""),"l","","en-GB")

]%%
```

inside the email to then turn that date into the 'long' description date.

I would look at finding a way to optimize the query for converting the date - e.g. only run it on new records (e.g. those that do not have a value in `ORDER_DATE_FORMAT` or similar.)